# How to print out list of elements in a designated format nicely?

Tags: python, printing, format

I have to print out elements of 2 lists in a designated format. For example,

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and

```
list2 = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I want to print out like

```
"a: 1, b: 2, c: 3"
```

I could write code like,

```
print("{}: {}, {}: {}, {}: {}".format(list1[0], list2[0],  list1[1], list2[1],  list1[2], list2[2])
```

But the number of elements of the 2 lists is uncertain, so I wonder how can I repeat the format in order to print out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two sequences are of the same length:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = ["1", "2", "3"]

print(', '.join('{}: {}'.format(a, b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)))
```

Outputs:

```
a: 1, b: 2, c: 3
```

In Python 3.6+, you can use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) to do it a little more succinctly:

```
print(', '.join(f'{a}: {b}' for a, b in zip(list1, list2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
for letter, number in zip(list1, list2):
    print(f"{letter}: {number}")
```

That will work, but you may also want to consider using a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}
print(my_dict)
```

The best option may just be a combination of both:

```
print(dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

But this will only work if `list1` and `list2` are the same size